# Show that $K[X]/(P)$ is the splitting field of $P$.

Tags: polynomials, field-theory

Let $K$ a field and $P\in K[X]$ and irreducible polynomial. The fact that $K[X]/(P)$ is a field is fine. I want to show that it's the smallest field where that split $P$.

First, let show that $K[X]/(P)$ split $P$. Suppose $\alpha $ is a root of $P$. Then, $P(\alpha )=0$. Consider $g(X)=X+P(X)\in K[X]/(P)$. We have that $g(\alpha )=\alpha $.

**Question 1 : Can I conclude that $\alpha \in K[X]/(P)$ ? Somethings looks strange to me, $K[X]/(P)$ is a "set" of polynomial, whereas $\alpha $ is an element of a field... so, how can I conclude ?**

Let $L$ a field that split $P$. If $\alpha $ is a root of $P$, then it's in $K[X]/(P)$ (since by the previous part, if $\alpha $ is a root, it's in $K[X]/(P)$). Now, by definition, it's also in $L$, and thus $K[X]/(P)\subset L$.

**Question 2 : Is it correct ? It look to simple, no ?**

Comment: I don't think this is true. $\mathbb{Q}/(x^3-2)$ is not the splitting field of $x^3-2$ but rather simply the smallest field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that includes $\alpha=\sqrt[3] 2$. In this field, $x^3-2=(x-\alpha)(x^2-\alpha x+\alpha^2)$ and the latter factor is irreducible.

Comment: $K[X]/(P)$ is a set of *equivalence classes* of polynomials.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Since $K[X]$ is principal and $(P)$ irreducible, it's also a field !

Comment: @Surb, my point is that "is a set of polynomial(s)" isn true.

Comment: Just for the terminology : $K[X]/(P)$ is a [rupture field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupture_field) of $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$K[X]/(P)$ for some field $K$ and $P \in K[X]$ is not necessarily the splitting field of $P$. For example, $\mathbb{Q}/(x^3-2)$ is not the splitting field of $x^3-2$ but rather simply the smallest field extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ that includes $\alpha=\sqrt[3] 2$. In this field, $x^3-2=(x-\alpha)(x^2-\alpha x+\alpha^2)$ and the latter factor is irreducible. The latter factor can be shown to be irreducible using the quadratic formula and then finding that it included the $\sqrt{-3}$ which is not in $\mathbb{Q}/(x^3-2)$.

I think what you really want to prove is that $K[X]/(P)$ is isomorphic the smallest field extension of $K$ containing some root of $P$. The following is a proof of this from ["Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications"](http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20130816.pdf), Chapter 21, page 339. Here, the smallest field extension containing some root of $P$ is $K(\alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $P$. Also, $E$ is a field extension containing $\alpha$.

> Let $\phi_\alpha : F[X] → E$ be the evaluation homomorphism. The kernel of this map is $(p(x))$, where $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. By the First Isomorphism Theorem for rings, the image of $\phi_\alpha$ in $E$ is isomorphic to $F(\alpha)$ since it contains both $F$ and $\alpha$.

Thus, the image of the evaluation homomorphism $\phi_\alpha$ contains all of the elements of $F$ because constants are polynomials and $\alpha$ because $\phi_\alpha(x)=\alpha$. It is also the smallest such ring because the image of this homomorphism must be in the smallest ring containing $F$ and $\alpha$ because polynomials are simply additions and multiplications of $\alpha$ and elements of $F$, which can all be done within a field. Also, the image of this homomorphism is $F[X]/(p(x))$ by the First Isomorphism Theorem for rings.  We must now prove $F[X]/(p(x))$ is a field, which is done [at this proof](http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/quotient-rings-of-polynomial-rings/quotient-rings-of-polynomial-rings.html) by [Bruce Ikenaga](http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/). Therefore, $F[X]/(p(x))$ is the smallest field extension of $F$ containing $\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are a bit confused. If $\alpha $ is a root of $P$, then the field $$K(\alpha )\cong K[X]/(P).$$
As you can see, if $\alpha _1,...,\alpha _n$ are all roots of $P$, then $$K(\alpha _1)\cong...\cong K(\alpha _n)\cong K[X]/(P)$$
but you definitely don't have $K(\alpha _1,...,\alpha _n)\cong K[X]/(P)$.

$K(\alpha )$ is the splitting field of $P$ only if the extension $K(\alpha )/K$ is normal. Otherwise, the splitting field of $P$ is just $K(\alpha _1,...,\alpha _n)$ where $\{\alpha _1,...,\alpha _n\}$ are all the roots of $P$.